# Converting base-6 number to base-2 (binary) using commands or a program

Tags: linux, conversion, numeric-data

I have a base-6 number generated by rolling a physical six-sided dice and want to convert it into base-2 / binary.

Are there built-in commands or programs that can do that for me?

If not, what is the manual way of converting the numbers?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199615/understand-ibase-and-obase-in-case-of-conversions-with-bc

Answer (score 2):

Like Jeff hints in the comments, you can use `bc` for base conversion. With regard to physical dice, the digits are usually 1 to 6, while `bc` (and maths) will need digits 0 to 5, so you need to do something about that, either manually, or with something like `tr`.

For example, this function would map `111` -> 0, `112` -> 1, `121` -> 6 etc.:

```
f() { 
    echo "obase=10; ibase=6; $(echo $1 | tr 1-6 0-5)" | bc;
}
```

The output is in decimal, you can change that by changing the value of `obase` above. Or you can use the decimal number for other arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

## Manually

```
Set total to 0
Repeat until no more roles:
  multiply total by 6 #this has no effect the first time around the loop
  role dice
  add (number on dice -1) to total
```

## Software

See other answers and comments

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of POSIX tools to convert from base 6 to base 2.

However, the symbols in a dice are `1 2 3 4 5 6` while a base-6 integer should use only the symbols `0 1 2 3 4 5`, there is a difference of 1. Any tool used must take that into account. For a single digit, that is not a big issue:

The simplest is bc (or dc). The conversion of a single digit could be done as:

```
digit=5; echo "n=$digit - 1; obase=2; n" | bc
```

But for several rolls in one string, like `31256` it needs to be input as a decimal number and subtract 1 from each digit (`11111` in this case) and then re-input as a base-6 number.

```
$ echo "ibase=6; obase=2; $(echo "31256-11111" | bc)" | bc
101001100001
```

Or, as text, you can convert every 6 to 5, every 5 to 4, etc.:

```
$ echo "ibase=6; obase=2; $(echo "31256" | tr 123456 012345)" | bc
101001100001
```

Another option is awk:

```
awk -v n=31256 '
            function roll2dec(str,    ret, i, c){
        for (i = 1; i <= length(str); i++) {
                    c = substr(str, i, 1)
                ret = ret * 6 + index("23456", c)
            }
            return ret
        }
            function dec2bin(dec,    bin){
                while (dec>0){ 
                    bin = dec%2 bin;
                    dec=int(dec/2) 
                };
                return bin
            }
  BEGIN{

  print dec2bin(roll2dec(n))

  }'

101001100001
```